# Clear data from SalesForceChat

Tags: lightning, liveagent, chat, embedded-services

I'm using SalesForce Lightning Chat ESW version 5.0

When a user logs out from our site we want to clear all active chat sessions for that user.

Our implementation is basically:

1. When the user logs out, the page is reloaded and we set a cookie called RememberToClearTheChat
2. we initialize our chat by loading a Salesforce-script `myOrganizationDomain/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js` and then we set up some config stuff like `embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true;` and then we do a call to `embedded_svc.init` with a bunch of params.
3. Once `embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI` has been loaded, we check if the user has a cookie called RememberToClearTheChat and in that case we do `embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.endChat(); embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.clearSession();`

It works sometimes for some users - but in some cases it randomly throws errors.

The errors are thrown during `clearSession()`. They are thrown by the a script called `aura_prod.js` which salesforce loads internally. An example error is `Uncaught Error: deleteSessionData requires two non-null arguments (domain, keys)`. Seems like the data is cleared halfway, and we end up in a semi broken state.

The desired result would be that the chat should be 'reset' to the default state, which is a minimized button that basically just says "start chat".

But the actual result is that the user sees an expanded chat window with an input field, but without a connected agent. So you can write messages that no one will see. And there's no UI avaiable to 'end chat' to get out of this faulty state.

Screenshot below: In this image you just see the default-label "Agent" - that's incorrect. In a functioning chat you should either be shown a "you have spot X in our queue" or you should see the name & avatar of a real agent.

**Question:**
Should we clear the chat using a different method?

or do we need to wait for some specific event before running `clearSession()` ?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am also getting same error, how did u solve yours. `deleteSessionData requires two non-null arguments`

Comment: I think I did. But looking at my old code I'm not quite sure how. We basically run the same code in OP before leaving the page AND while a new pageview is loading the chat (in that case we wait with a timer until `embedded_svc` is defined)

Comment: @R15 : posted a bit more as an Answer. Hopefully it helps. It's so stupid - but the 'solution' is simply to try 2 times and HOPE that the next time the chat is loaded you can clear the previous session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in case anyone finds this post.

We kept using the same methods mentioned in the OP

`embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.endChat(); embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI.clearSession();`

but we called them during 2 separate events

1. On leaving the chat - try to clear the current session (this works sometimes)
2. On loading the chat - try to clear the previous session (this works sometimes)

Doing both of these means it'll work most of the time, but it is a flaky hack.

Step 1: Do this before leaving the current session

```
if (embedded_svc && embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI){
    document.cookie = "RememberToClearTheChat";
    clearChat();
    return;
}
```

Step2: Every time you load the chat check for that cookie - and if it exists - run this code within a `setInterval` function every 500ms or so for 10 seconds. And pray that it works.

```
if (typeof embedded_svc !== "undefined") {
        const foundLiveAgentApi = embedded_svc.liveAgentAPI;
        if (foundLiveAgentApi) {
            clearInterval(waitForLiveAgentInterval);
            clearChat(shouldLogOutAfterClearingChat);
        }
}
```

A flaky solution that might not be 100% effective but was good enough for us to ship since it's "better than nothing".

EDIT: I should mention that the variable `liveAgentAPI` is lazy loaded so you must wait for it to be created before running this code. We ended up polling for it every 500 ms with 30 attempts using `setInterval` and a counter.

Comment: It says liveAgentAPI is undefined, any idea what I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: @DaniyalNasir Lucky enough I remember this problem exactly! liveAgentAPI is lazy-loaded, it can take some time for it to be created. We wrote a setInterval function that ran every 500ms, up to 30 times - checking if liveAgentAPI exists. Then we run our code after it's we know it exists.